# Access Denied while accessing http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ page

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have installed xampp in opensuse13.2. It got installed neatly. But I am getting following error while accessing http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ page. I tried few answers over here but none are helping, like setting password as '' or ' '. Trying to authenticate over 'http' instead of 'config'. But none is working.

MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings.
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Below is the content of phpmyadmin/config.inc.php file.

```html
/**
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/**
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
/* Server parameters */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/**
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
 */

/* User used to manipulate with storage */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = '';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlport'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'root';

/* Storage database and tables */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line to

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
```

to

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

and try logging in with no password

and also change this lines

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'root';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
```

update: restart after modifying the lines. you had this following line in your code which allows the user login without password that's the above code works after deleting the passwords

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest try setting the password and controlpass to `'';` instead of `'root';`.

P.S. It might be helpful to post what you have tried so far. So that we won't repeat possible solutions.

P.P.S. I cannot comment, and adding another answer seems inappropriate, so I would simply edit this one.

Maybe you can set the port? The standard one is 80, but it is sometimes used by other programs (like Skype, for example). So you might want to use 8080. But then you should change localhost to localhost:8080.

P.P.P.S. Perhaps you already found that, but here are some links that might provide useful info: 
http://www.prestadocumentation.com/how-to-install-phpmyadmin/
http://wpquestions.com/question/showChrono/id/8374

Comment: I tried, it didn't work. Also, I got " Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed." error as well. Ok, I will update what all I tried.